# loading BufferedImage with ClassLoader.getResource()

Tags: java, image, classloader, bufferedimage

I am trying to load an image file (gif) which is stored locally in the same directory as my Eclipse java project:

`ref` is the relative path where the gif image is stored.

```
public Sprite getSprite(String ref) {
      BufferedImage sourceImage = null;
      try {
        URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(ref);        
        if (url == null) {
        fail("Can't find ref: "+ref);
       }
       sourceImage = ImageIO.read(url);
       } catch (IOException e) {
        fail("Failed to load: "+ref);
       }
}
```

The client code that uses the above method is:

```
public Entity(String ref,int x,int y) {
        this.sprite = ResourceManager.getSprite("sprites/alien.gif");
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
```

In the Eclipse workspace and within my project directory I have a folder `sprites`with the gif images stored there. But the client code always returns: `Can't find ref: sprites/ship.gif`

Am I doing something wrong in my approach above to load the gif image? Is there a better more straightforward way to do a file lookup in this case?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question you ask, but technically, an Sprite is a Object with position, texture, etc etc, and that you are trying to load in here is a "Texture" instead of a Sprite , is just for your knowledge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getResource()` method searches your *classpath* to find the file, likely the *sprites* directory is not in your classpath.

Try open your project properties -> `Java Build Path`, select `Libraries` tab and click on `Add Class Folder` button then select the parent directory of *sprites*.

Comment: I think you mean the parent directory of the sprites directory, don't you?

Comment: Yes, that did the trick actually! The parent directory that is

Comment: you are right, I fixed the answer to point to parent directory

Comment: You have no idea how long I've looked for this answer.
Thx!