# How can I debug resources path loading or the ClassLoader in general?

Tags: java, netbeans, embedded-resource

I've read up some questions by people having problems loading resources. I have followed the instructions they've got (though these instructions actually differ which means either were incorrect - I tried all).

I created `enum` to load the resources for me when needed. It's long but I'll share it in case somebody came here from google and could make use of it:

```
package cz.autoclient.GUI;
/**
 * Enum of resources used for GUI. These resources are packed in .jar and are for internal use.
 * Provides lazy-loaded Image and ImageIcon for comfort.
 * @author Jakub
 */
public enum ImageResources {
  ICON("IconHighRes.png");
  //So according to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17007533/607407) I
  //  should enter classpath beginning with slash to make sure it's absolute path from
  //  the root of my .jar
  public static final String basepath = "/cz/autoclient/resources/";
  //Cache everything to have less letters to write
  public static final ClassLoader loader = ImageResources.class.getClassLoader();
  public static final Class leclass = ImageResources.class;
  //String is immutable so it's ok to make it a public constant
  public final String path;
  //These will fill up on demand when needed
  private ImageIcon icon;
  private Image image = null;
  //If image has failed, we'll not try to load it again and will return null straight away
  private boolean image_failed = false;
  //Constructor concatenates the individual path with the global path
  ImageResources(String path) {
    this.path = basepath+path;
  }

  /** Loads, or just retrieves from cache, the image.
   *  @return Image (not necesarily a BufferedImage) or null on failure
  */
  public Image getImage() {
    //Lazy load...
    if(image==null) {
      //Since the .jar is constant (it's packed) we can
      //Remember the image is unavailable
      if(image_failed)
        return null;
      //Use whatever is stored in Icon if we have it
      if(icon!=null) {
        image = icon.getImage();
      }
      //Load from .jar
      else {
        try {
          image = ImageIO.read(leclass.getResourceAsStream("/images/grass.png"));
        }
        //While only IOException is reported it also can throw InvalidArgumentException
        // when read() argument is null
        catch(Exception e) {
          image_failed = true;
        }
      }
    }
    return image;
  }
}
```

<sup>[Full version on GitHub.](https://github.com/Darker/auto-client/blob/master/src/cz/autoclient/GUI/ImageResources.java) Can be subject to change.</sup>

Since this code doesn't work (due to invalid base path) I want to know a general way to find **why are the resources not loading** and **where is the `ClassLoader` looking**.

For example when I had problems loading normal file from filesystem, I could do this:

```
File relativePath = new File("../my_test_image.png");
System.out.println(relativePath.getAbsolutePath());
```

And I could immediately see where's Java looking and what should I change. If I as well as others know a simple way to do this with resources, all these questions wouldn't need to be asked:

- [Getting a BufferedImage as a resource so it will work in JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17007448/607407)
- [loading BufferedImage with ClassLoader.getResource()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1799371/607407)
- [java getResource() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12440035/607407)
- [Resource loading in Java not working as it should](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9615150/607407)
- [How to correctly get image from 'Resources' folder in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6845231/607407)

So is there a way to **print what does my resource path translate to?**

What I tried:

- [`((URLClassLoader) (Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())).getURLs();`](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/)
- [`System.out.println(" Current path: \""+loader.getResource("ImageResources.class")+"\")");`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/227569/607407) - prints `Current path: "null"`

Comment: `((URLClassLoader) (Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())).getURLs();` doesn't work for you?

Comment: That prints lot of maven dependencies. Also, the results are actually filesystem absolute paths: http://pastebin.com/msK76bvB

Comment: `leclass.getResourceAsStream("/images/grass.png")`
will try to load "grass.png" via classloader of "leclass" from the "images" package. Package will need to be in the same directory (or .jar) as leclass class.

Comment: For me it didn't work because I was running test class (Maven) which runs in different directory. But how do libraries handle this? They have no problems running in test classes directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems you can always get the current path by this statement:

```
System.out.println("  Path: \""+loader.getResource(".")+"\"");
```

For me, this gives:

```
  Path: "file:/C:/... path to project .../PROJECT_NAME/target/test-classes/"
```

This is a path of the test class running the test, not the actual class `loader` it has been created for. I do not think this is a bug.